# 3D Single Cube Slider Effect

Tags: jquery, html, 3d, cube, effect

I need some assistance on the 3D Single Cube Slider Effect for Image Siders. I would like to implement this effect into this slider http://jsfiddle.net/hZ4yk/14/ . This effect will rotate the image in a cube shape. Thank You for your help.

```
        <div class="anyClass">

            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/365x500/000544/000000" alt="" width="365" height="500" ></li>
                <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/365x500/555/000000" alt="" width="365" height="500" ></li>
                <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/365x500/465400/0011ff" alt="" width="365" height="500" ></li>
                <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/365x500/520700/00ffe1" alt="" width="365" height="500" ></li>
                <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/365x500/245200/ff0000" alt="" width="365" height="500" ></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
                    </div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext:".next",
    btnPrev:".prev",
    visible: 1,
    speed: 500
    });
    });


    .next
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 290px; 
    width:64px;
    z-index:10;
    }

    .prev
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px; 
    width:64px;
    z-index:10;
    }

    .linknext
    {
    cursor:pointer;
    }

    .linkprev
    {
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Comment: it's of course possible if you implement the *carousel* yourself, not sure if there is some way to add some 3d effect using the carousellite plugin. I guess that the transition between images implemented by carousellite is **translate** transform, or something like that (the image is translated **in a flat**). So there is no chance to use other CSS transforms such as `rotate3d`, ... to create 3d effect.

Comment: @KingKing do you know of any good 3d cube sliders that I can put into my site. That is easy to manipulate?

Comment: sorry I've not known of any as well as have not coded any like that. I think searching may help you find something similar.